# FIleNotFoundException when I am trying to save a file

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

I have put the following permissions to my manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

The following is the function on which the compiler is showing error:

```
private void save(String s) {
    FileOutputStream stream = null;

    File notes = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/SystemService", "samples.txt");
    Log.i(LOGTAG, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/SystemService");

    try {
        stream = new FileOutputStream(notes);
        stream.write(s.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

SystemService is the folder name where I want to store my newly created folder in which I want the text files to be stored on my external storage device. (I have a marshmallow running device and I have given storage permission to the app)

The exact error is

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/SystemService/samples.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: What is your app `targetSdkVersion`? You may not be using the legacy permission system. From `L` onwards, you must ask permissions during execution.

Comment: @Harshit I am not sure but seems like your folder SystemService is not getting created. Do one thing just before your log.i method do notes.mkdirs() .

Comment: I am using     targetSdkVersion as 23 but I have given storage permissions to this app from the Settings

Comment: For `Version 23` you need to give Run time permissions check this http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @Bonatti Not sure why you refer `Marshmallow` as `L`...

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I dont. `L` is API 22, `M` is API 23... on `K` API 19, some changes started happening and were set as default on `L`, that the Permission system was migrating from static XML (Manifest) refferences on install, to an on demand Permission system. However, for compatibility, if your targetSK is still 19 (or lower), the old system apply.

Comment: @Bonatti `From L onwards, you must ask permissions during execution.`. I assume `L` stands for Lollipop. If so, your statement is just wrong **Runtime permissions** are from 6.0: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski You are correct, its not API 22, the change happened in API 23.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the FileNotFoundException,  create the missing folders, if needed by calling [File#mkdirs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()).  Here is an example with some minor clean up (logging of exceptions, deleting older file if it exists). HTHs!

```
private void save(String s) {
    FileOutputStream stream = null;
    File notes = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "SystemService/samples.txt");
    if (!notes.exists()) {
        // creates the missing folders for this file
        notes.mkdirs();
    }
    Log.i(LOGTAG, notes.getAbsolutePath().toString());

    try {
        stream = new FileOutputStream(notes);
        stream.write(s.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // use log.e for errors
        Log.e(LOGTAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOGTAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

From the [File#mkdirs documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs())

> Creates the directory named by this file, creating missing parent directories if necessary. Use mkdir() if you don't want to create missing parents.

Comment: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory) Now, this error pops up. And when I went to the exact location where the file was saved, It shows a folder named "samples.txt" not a file. I guess mkdirs() creates a directory not a file

Comment: `notes.mkdirs();`. You shoud check the return value as probably you cannot create a diretory there. `if (!notes.mkdirs()) return false:`. So make it a boolean function too which tells you if the file could be saved. Void is not informative.

Comment: `notes.delete();` ??? So the second time you will delete that directory before trying to write a file in it?????

Comment: I think you miss up the file and the folder. It should be notes.getParentFile().mkdirs().

Comment: notes.delete() will just delete the file.  not the folders that were create when mkdirs noticed they were missing.

Comment: You dont need to delete the file. That will be done by new FileOutputStream.

Comment: You are creating a directory with the file name. So you will never be able to write a file with the same name as that directory.

Comment: `open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)`. Listen!